# How to reset a search using android SearchManager

Tags: android, search, reset, searchmanager

I have one Activity with a fragment to list some data. I've already implemented the search using the SearchView (the nice looking search field on action bar).

The search is working fine, user input the data, press the search button and the results are filtered as expected.

My problem is that I can't "reset" the search back to all results. I already tried setting the Dismiss and Cancel listenners on the searchManager object but the onDismiss and oncancel methods are never being called.

Here is my action on the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ClientesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_clientes"
        android:parentActivityName=".MenuPrincipalActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="MenuPrincipalActivity" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/cliente_searchable" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The methods on the ClientesActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    clientesService = new ClientesService(getBaseContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clientes);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, ClienteFragment.newInstance(), ClienteFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                .commit();
    }
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        clientesService.findByNameLike(query);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.clientes, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    return true;
}
```

It's not showing the Listenners because I rolled back the changes after nothing worked.
But basically o added the listenners before the 'return true' on the onCreateOptionsMenu method.
It was nothing fancy at first, just annonymous class overriding the interface with onDismiss method implemented, tried to put some logs there and the method was never called.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reset'? Press cross / remove all text from search area?

Comment: Going back to all results. The cross is working fine.
I already have the methods that returns all the records but the OnDismiss/OnCancel events are never called.

Comment: Which is exact scenario then? How do you want to go back to 'all results'? Does 'clientesService.findByNameLike()' return 'all results' if you pass empty string/null?

Comment: The scenario is, i tried to bind the Cancel listenner on the search manager to execute some code when the user closes the search widget pressing back button, but this event is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `android.widget.SearchView#setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener`. As far as I can tell the hasFocus will be true when the searchview is displayed and will not be called again with false until the user hits the upstack/back arrow to close the search. Oddly, I never see `android.widget.SearchView#setOnCloseListener` called

Alternately, implement an onOptionsItemSelected and call android.app.Activity#onSearchRequested() to trigger the search dialog in order to have those registered callback methods utilized.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();//delegate upstream
            break;
         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
    }
```

It's not very clear in the [Invoking the search dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#InvokingTheSearchDialog) documentation. I don't see it declared in the documentation. But it seems if you use just the search widget, the SearchManager callbacks are not triggered.